# Добавление в корзину битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Добрый день. Возникла проблема с добавлением в корзину товара по ID. На кнопку вешаю скрипт, который передает в файл ID товара (все передается, я проверил). Файл выглядит так:

```
 if (CModule::IncludeModule("catalog"))
   {
        $result = Add2BasketByProductID($_GET['id1']);
        file_put_contents('example.txt', $result, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        file_put_contents('example.txt', $_GET['id1'], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
   }
```

В создавшемся файле (А это значит, что скрипт сработал) написан только ID товара, а вот функция добавления в корзину ничего не возвратила, и товар не добавила. В чем может быть проблема, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
CModule::IncludeModule("sale");
$result = Add2BasketByProductID($_GET["id1"]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но функция Add2BasketByProductID все - равно не сработала. Решил проблему через жо.у! Вытаскивал из массива урл добавления в корзину, и отправлял на него пустой GET запрос. Может, поможет такой вариант тому, кто, как и я, должен добиться результата, а не разбираться в косяках битрикса =)